ASP.NET Core Web API on beanstalk - How to change URL Swagger
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, and I've created a Beanstalk environment on AWS to launch the API. I can load the API locally using https://localhost:7182/swagger/index.html.
However I can't figure out how to get the beanstalk URL to load the same API.
I've tried changing the URL address of the project, Project properties > Debug > General > Open debug launch profiles URL > [projectname] > URL and entered the URL of the beanstalk environment instead of 'swagger'. This loads the URL in the browser but the API doesn't load on the webpage.
I've read this thread How to change base url of Swagger in ASP.NET core , specifically this:
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MY API");
}

I don't understand where to add my URL, anyone able to help please?

Delete this condition in you Program.cs file. After publishing the project, the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in beanstalk is Production.
Then you can access your swagger ui page via ： https://your_url.com .
 if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
     
 }


